# LaunchExternsl doesn't work in intel xdk android app

Tags: android, intel, intel-xdk

I have a question for you...I have complete my app in intel xdk this app will show a TV stream on VLC app when user click on image in my app so I used LaunchExternal , it seem to do good job on emulator but it's not working on real android device "I used mms://192.168.157.5:5746.mp4 as a url in LaunchExternal"

please,help me

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to setup your whitelist in the build settings section of the projects tab.

Note that the Emulate tab does not represent the behavior of a real device, it is simply a "Cordova API simulator" -- despite the name.